# jQuery page fading and strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, strict

I want use a fadeout effect on links. If i use the normal mode everythings working good.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.transition").click(function (e) {
   event.preventDefault();
   newLocation = this.href;
   $("body").fadeOut(1000, function () {
      window.location = newLocation;
  });
  });
});
```

But I must use strict mode

```
(function($){
"use strict";
 .....
 .....
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.transition").click(function (e) {
   event.preventDefault();
   newLocation = this.href;
   $("body").fadeOut(1000, function () {
      window.location = newLocation;
  });
  });

  .....
  init other functions
  ....
});
})(jQuery);
```

And it's not working strict mode. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try testing your code with the tool http://jslint.com/, and fix it until it passes. "use strict" disables certain javascript functionalities that are pretty bad, so you'll have to rewrite your code so you rid yourself of all these bad things. If you post all of  your code here, we might help you with what's missing.

Comment: Now I'm change the newLocation = this.href; with var newLocation = this.href; it's working but this time fade effect is not working only white screen seen and after that url changed.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(newLocation) to make sure everything works at it should?

Answer (score 0):

Try this! If it doesn't work, check your javascript console and see what's there?

```
$("a.transition").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var newLocation = $(this).prop("href");

   $("body").fadeOut(1000, function () {
       window.location.href = newLocation;
   });
});
```

Comment: It's working but fade effect is not working firstly white screen coming and after that url redirect.

Comment: I think i found the error, try the code now? The problem was that you send e as the event in you function, but then you do event.preventDefault(), changing that to e.preventDefault might do the trick.